# HTTP 404 Not Found after successful Spring Security authentication

Tags: spring, security, authentication

I am trying to implement Spring Security Authentication and Authorization using Database. Spring security authentication is working good.  But I am getting HTTP 404 NOT FOUND page with URL /Sample_App/j_spring_security_check, instead of default-target-url it should goto.

Here is my spring-security file

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:import resource="im-jndi-datasource.xml" />

    <http pattern="/inventory/auth/login" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/inventory/auth/deny" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>

    <http auto-config="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/inventory/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />   

        <form-login 
            login-page="/inventory/auth/login" 
            default-target-url="/inventory/landing/loadDashBoardPage"
            authentication-failure-url="/inventory/auth/login?error"
            username-parameter="username" 
            password-parameter="password" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/inventory/auth/deny"/>  

        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

        <session-management
            session-authentication-error-url="/inventory/auth/login" 
            invalid-session-url="/inventory/auth/login">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exce    eded="true"/>
        </session-management>

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
        <!-- <security:user-service> <security:user name="dineshonjava" password="sweety" 
                authorities="ROLE_USER" /> </security:user-service> -->
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, status as enabled from bbp_user where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select us.username, ur.rolename as authority from bbp_user us, bbp_users_and_roles bur, bbp_role ur     
    where us.user_id = bur.user_id and bur.role_id =ur.role_id  and us.username =? " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is the part of spring-servlet.xml file

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/eimsgo-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/inventory/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
        </filter-mapping>
```

I use tiles2.TilesViewResolver and ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Here is my tiles-context xml

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
      <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
          <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
          <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
          <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
      </property>        
      <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
      </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/jsp/</value> 
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

My welcome file index.jsp hits the LoginController.java with URL (/inventory/auth/login)

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class LoginController {  
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
        @RequestParam(value = "invalid", required = false) String invalid) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    if(invalid != null) {
        model.addObject("invalid", "Invalid session!!");
    }
    model.setViewName("home_creation");

    return model;
}
```

}

After successful login, it should goto /inventory/landing/loadDashBoardPage as per default-target-url defined in the security xml file.

Where /landing is one of my Spring Controller, and loadDashBoarPage is method level mapping.  The loadDashBoardPage interacts with the database and set the Map object and retuns the View string "DashBoardPage".  TilesViewResolver now should render this page.

InventoryController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/landing")
public class InventoryController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/loadDashBoardPage" }, method = { GET, POST })
public String loadDashBoardPage(Map<String, Object> model,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    List lobList = new ArrayList();
    InventoryService inventoryService = (InventoryService) InventoryApplicationContext
            .getBean("inventoryService");
    lobList = inventoryService.loadLob();
    model.put("lob", lobList);
    model.put("leftTreee", inventoryService.loadDataforNavigator());
    return "DashBoardPage";
}
```

Please find the log below

2014-12-05 22:55:27,419 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction commit

2014-12-05 22:55:27,420 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager  - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.237.31.14:1521:xe, UserName=ADMIN, Oracle JDBC driver]

2014-12-05 22:55:27,422 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager  - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.237.31.14:1521:xe, UserName=ADMIN, Oracle JDBC driver] after transaction

2014-12-05 22:55:27,422 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

2014-12-05 22:55:27,425 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG **org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver  - Requested media types are [image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*] (based on Accept header)**

2014-12-05 22:55:27,425 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'DashBoardPage.atom'

2014-12-05 22:55:27,426 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'DashBoardPage.json'

2014-12-05 22:55:27,429 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'DashBoardPage.html'

**2014-12-05 22:55:27,430 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver  - Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView: name 'DashBoardPage'; URL [DashBoardPage]] based on requested media type '*/*'**

2014-12-05 22:55:27,430 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView: name 'DashBoardPage'; URL [DashBoardPage]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

2014-12-05 22:55:27,430 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView  - Added model object 'lob' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'DashBoardPage'

2014-12-05 22:55:27,431 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView  - Added model object 'leftTreee' of type [java.util.HashMap] to request in view with name 'DashBoardPage'

**2014-12-05 22:55:27,431 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer  - Render request recieved for definition 'DashBoardPage'**

2014-12-05 22:55:27,432 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request

2014-12-05 22:55:27,432 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally

2014-12-05 22:55:27,432 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

**Spring Security authenticates successfully** here and the view resolver is not rendering the requested page.

Instead I am getting **http://abc.xyz.com/Sample_App/j_spring_security_check**

It should allow the user to goto the URL as defined in the default-target-url

**/Sample_App/inventory/landing/loadDashBoardPage**

Please advise!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue myself.  Spring Security tightly intercepts all the URLs including CSS, Images, JavaScripts, JSP files and everything.

The problem here is, I am using TilesViewResolver

```
<definition name="LogoutPage" template="/jsp/logout.jsp"> 
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/tiles/logoutHeader.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/jsp/tiles/footer.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/logout_creation.jsp" />
</definition>
```

I forget to configure the spring security that intercept all the sub-URLs that these tiles pages use with authentication based on roles.